# How to put your Jenkins console output on a GitHub status page?

Tags: github, jenkins

I am using Jenkins with GitHub.
My Jenkins is run on a server and polls the GitHub repo all the time for new commits.
When a commit is made, the Jenkins job gets run and I even see the status on GitHub:

[image]

However, if I click on ***Details***, it opens the status of the build on Jenkins:

[image]

If I want to see why the job failed then I click on "Console Output" on the left

[image]

and see the output:
[image]

***The issue:***
I would prefer to be able to see the console output on GitHub itself similarly to how you see the status of a GitHub app (for example in the two images below) like this:

[image]

[image]

edit: or go to this [link](https://github.com/SoftaCheck/test-repo-cpp/commit/0daf4ce44c324f38ad74e30c971bb5cf8899379e) and check it for yourself.

Is this possible?

Comment: #1 Is that detail page a part of git repository, like wiki? #2 Search and share us a link of real and public git repository with that "details" option to take a look at it.

Comment: @JRichardsz I added a link per your suggestion.